# return vs print in conditional statements within a loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to understand why the second function with the return inside the conditionals, will only loop once.
l = [1,2,3,45,6,7]
First working example with print:

```
def xyz(l):
    for i in l:
        if i==7:
            print('7 found')
        else:
            print('7 not found')
```

xyz(l)

Output:

```
7 not found
7 not found
7 not found
7 not found
7 not found
7 found
```

Now the function with return statement:

```
def xyz(l):
    for i in l:
        if i==7:
            return '7 found'
        else:
            return '7 not found'
```

Result:

```
'7 not found'
```

The loop runs only once for the first element and returns the else value. 
Please don`t downvote this, this is a thing I need to understand before continuing to learn python.
Does the return statement exit the loop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because this is what `return` is doing. It **returns** from the function, which will stop any loop. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement)

Comment: @DeepSpace I expected it to loop through all the elements first before quitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'return' word ends the execution of the function, 'return *something*' means the value the function is trying to achieve is: *something*; it can be visualized as the answer of the function.

'print' word only displays a certain string (text) on the console.